# Updating Rows in a normalized table

Tags: sql, normalization

normalized table

```
ID SEQ Type Value Flag
1  1   a    100   -
1  2   a    200   -
1  3   a    250   -
1  4   b    200   -
2  1   a    150   -
2  2   b    100   -
2  3   b    200   -
```

How do I write a single update statement such that the resulting table is populated as follows

```
ID SEQ Type Value Flag
1  1   a    100   valid
1  2   a    200   repeat
1  3   a    250   repeat
1  4   b    200   valid
2  1   a    150   valid
2  2   b    100   valid
2  3   b    200   repeat
```

Edit: included seq column

only the first occurence of the value for a type for a ID group should have the valid flag
should it be written as two separate update statements?
can someone clarify me?
Much appreciated

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: @zealous , Oracle

Comment: and are you populating  normalized table?

Comment: @zealous, yes the table is populated but the flag column will be null at first

Comment: @zealous, included a seq column

Comment: What do you mean, "normalized table", and what does that have to do with your question? PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS You were told on tagging with sql to tag with your DBMS.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Clearly explain why you are stuck & show what you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populate the table first using `row_number()` and then update the table.

Option 1:

```
select
    Id,
    Type,
    Value,
    null as Flag,
    row_number() over (partition by ID, Type order by SEQ) as rnk
from yourTable
```

then  you can use `update`

```
update yourTable
set flag = case
                when rnk = 1 then 'valid'
                else 'repeat'
            end
```

Option 2:
You may be able to do without using `update` statement as following

```
select
    Id,
    SEQ,
    Type,
    Value,
    case
        when rnk = 1 then 'valid'
        else 'repeat'
    end as flag
from
(
    select
        Id,
        SEQ,
        Type,
        Value,
        row_number() over (partition by ID, Type order by SEQ) as rnk
    from yourTable
) val
```

Comment: @CrystalPaladin did not above update statement worked?

Comment: @CrystalPaladin try with the `update` statement I have provided above.

Comment: @CrystalPaladin happy to help.

Comment: is it possible to join the result of the rank with the table and use update in single statement?

Comment: @CrystalPaladin please give it a shot.